# How do I tidy survey data so that I can create a reactive bar plot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I'd like to create a reactive bar plot similar to this one and have been working with the source code: https://beta.rstudioconnect.com/jjallaire/shiny-embedding/#module.

My data has two columns:

1. year (1988, 1991, 1996, 2000, 2008, 2016, 2018)
2. a response to a particular question (options from 1-7)

Each row is equal to one person's response and I have about 18 000 of them. I want the year as the dropdown option that changes the chart and the bar chart to show the number of each response (1-7) each year.

I can see from the code used in the link that I should have the years in columns across the top and the survey responses 1-7 as rows, with the number of responses for each number in the dataframe. I just can't work out how to tidy the data into that format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should put your data in the form you are looking. Next time please provide a small dataframe to work with:

```
library(tidyverse)

result_df <- initial_df %>%
  select(year, response) %>%
  group_by(year, response) %>%
  summarise(n = n()) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = year, values_from = n)
```